# Mongodb: Use record count in aggregation after a group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to store the total number of records input to the pipe so I can use the number in a later calculation. How do I grab the number of inputs, then unwind, then use the number of inputs later in my calcs?

I can get the number by doing this:

```
db.articles.aggregate([
  {
    $count: "totalArticles"
  }
]}
```

I can get the rest of the data I want by doing this:

```
db.articles.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$concepts"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id:    "$concepts.text",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      average: {
        $avg: "$concepts.relevance"
      },
    }
  }
])
```

What I'd really like to do is this:

```
db.articles.aggregate([
  {
    $count: "totalArticles"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$concepts"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id:    "$concepts.text",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      average: {
        $avg: "$concepts.relevance"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      count: "$count",
      percent: {
        $divide: [ "$count", "$totalArticles" ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      count: -1
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation query.

Initial `$group` to calculate the total count while `$push` the concepts field into array field. `$$ROOT` to access the whole doc.

Retain the total articles count in next `$group`.

Rest all stays the way you've.

```
db.articles.aggregate([
  {"$group":{
    "_id":null,
    "totalArticles":{"$sum":1},
    "concepts":{"$push":"$$ROOT.concepts"}
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$concepts"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$concepts.text",
    "totalArticles":{"$first":"$totalArticles"},
    "count":{"$sum":1},
    "average":{"$avg":"$concepts.relevance"}
  }},
  {"$project":{
      "count": "$count",
      "percent": {
        "$divide": [ "$count", "$totalArticles" ]
      }
    }
  },
  {"$sort": {"count": -1}}
])
```

`$facets` is also an option where you can two queries in two separate pipeline followed by merge to continue with rest of stages.

Comment: That works well thank you! I've read about `$$ROOT` and understand there is a total memory size. Is there a way to reduce that by selecting fields at that stage with `$project`? As you can see I'm only using the `concepts` field in the rest of the calc.