# add metadata to mongo aggregation result

Tags: mongodb

Let's assume i have following entries in my mongo collection:

```
[{a: 1}, {a: 2}, ... {a: 10}]
```

Now i want to write an aggregation that returns only a few items but also returns the total count.

If you write two aggregations they would look like:

```
[ // meta info about total number of docs that matched
 { $match: {} },
 { $count: 'totalCount' }
]

[ // get first 5
 { $match: {} },
 { $limit: 5 }
] // totalCount should remain 10
```

Is it possible to combine this into one aggregation to safe some computation time?

Comment: Not sure how performant this will be, but you can use `db.col.aggregate([
      {"$group":{
        "_id":null,
        "count":{"$sum":1},
        "data":{"$push":"$$ROOT"}
      }},
      {"$unwind":"$data"},
      { $limit: 5 }
    ])`.`$group` to calculate the total count while `$push`ing  all the documents into array field followed by $unwind to go back to original structure. Sometimes its just better to do multiple queries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48307554/1110423

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$facet` for this, it traverse the document once

```
db.ad.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $facet : {
        metaInfo : [
          { $match : { "a" : 1 } },
          { $group : { _id : null, count : {$sum : 1} } }
        ],
        actualData : [
          { $match : { "a" : 1 } },
          { $limit : 2 }
        ]
      }
    }    
  ]
)
```

collection (has 5 a's )

```
> db.ad.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6a0f4076b4f3c119a8c751"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6a0f4076b4f3c119a8c752"), "a" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6a0f4076b4f3c119a8c753"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6a0f4076b4f3c119a8c754"), "a" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6a0f4076b4f3c119a8c755"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6a0f4076b4f3c119a8c756"), "a" : 6 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6a0f4076b4f3c119a8c757"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6a0f4076b4f3c119a8c758"), "a" : 8 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6a0f4076b4f3c119a8c759"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6a0f4076b4f3c119a8c75a"), "a" : 10 }
>
```

pipeline returned meta and actual data, meta has all the matching count and actual data has `$limit` applied

```
{
    "metaInfo" : [
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "count" : 5
        }
    ],
    "actualData" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a6a0f4076b4f3c119a8c751"),
            "a" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a6a0f4076b4f3c119a8c753"),
            "a" : 1
        }
    ]
}
>
```

Comment: For anything a little more complicated this is doubling the work load. Surely there should be some meta data you can get out of the original aggregation.